# How to implement our own Frame Encryptor in WebRTC C++?

Tags: android, c++, webrtc, jitsi

currently I am trying to modify webRTC for specialized purposes in Android. I need help with how we could use this interface to modify our frame after encoding.

For now I just really want to XOR the frame after encoding before sending it through PeerConnection. Since I am not familiar with C++, I tried to implement my own method inherited from this interface but it did not work.

My purpose is to use this one on android, that's why I could not use insertable stream on the web, so I should modify it directly in native C++.

I really appreciate any help! Thanks so much.

Here is my [ExampleTransformer](https://gist.github.com/alexivaner/c0c0b32e702e9ee9af16436c4601251f).h and [ExampleTransformer.cpp](https://gist.github.com/alexivaner/956ae7a9f8c02cad16d54ddd6c84ad97)

maybe someone could help me to show me where I could add my XOR FrameEncryptor based on this flow:

[image]

I am a bit stuck with C++, thank you so much for help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "please give me the codes" service

Comment: Sorry for that, I am mistaken my languages

Comment: Anyhow do you have experience with webrtc?